# Somar valor da coluna agrupando mensal e por produto

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, sqlfiddle

Pessoal estou precisando calcular o consumo mensal das licenças utilizadas aqui na empresa que trabalho.

Eu tenho uma tabela com o produto **(dbo.Product)**, o número de licenças instaladas no servidor **(dbo.License)** a data que o produto foi instalado **(dbo.FirstDate)** e a data de desinstalação **(dbo.DecomDate)**,  quando o produto ainda está instalado a data de desinstalação possui o valor NULL.

Tabela exemplo disponível no [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e70e0/2)

Gostaria de saber como somar o consumo de licenças agrupando por mês e por produto nos últimos 12 meses.

> Ex.:
>
> Date | Product | TotalLicense 
> 2017-08 | Adobe Photoshop | 8 
> 2017-08 | CorelDRAW | 5 
> 2017-09 |... 
> 2018-07 | Adobe Photoshop | 4 
> 2018-07 | CorelDRAW | 2

Tabela exemplo disponível no [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e70e0/2)

Comment: Se alguma das respostas resolveu seu problema, por favor marque-a como aceita!

Answer (score 1):

Teste este script aqui e veja se funciona de acordo com o que precisa

```
SELECT Product
      ,CAST(YEAR(FirstDate) AS CHAR(4)) 
       +RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(FirstDate) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS PERIODO
      ,SUM(License)                                          AS LICENSE
FROM Baseline
WHERE FirstDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY Product
        ,CAST(YEAR(FirstDate) AS CHAR(4)) 
         +RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(FirstDate) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Para testar no exemplo que você disponibilizou [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07948/4)

Answer (score 0):

A query que colocou no SQL Fiddle estava quase completa, só faltava agrupar por data e colocar a condição dos 12 meses:

```
SELECT      FirstDate       AS [Date]
        ,   Product         
        ,   SUM(License)    AS [TotalLicense]
FROM        Baseline
GROUP BY    FirstDate
        ,   Product
HAVING      FirstDate >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
ORDER BY    FirstDate
```